# Probability, expected value, variance, random variable

Tags: probability

Random variable has values 0,1,2,3,4,5
$$P[X=0]=P[X=1]=P[X=2]=a$$
$$P[X=3]=P[X=4]=P[X=5]=b$$
$$P[X\ge2]=3P[X<2]$$

I have to compute values of $a$ and $b$ parameters, expected value and variance.
I have some results and I want to make sure they're correct.
$a=\frac{1}{8},b=\frac{5}{24},E[X]=\frac{23}{8},var[X]=\frac{6767}{192}$
This is not my couple of tea so that's why I'm asking you for help. If needed, I'll add my step by step solution. Thanks.

Comment: They are absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Thank you all for your help. I was pretty sure my results were fine, but I have lack of self-confidence. Here's my solution, if someone wonders.
$3a+3b=1$, because sum of all probabilities equals to 1.
$3b=5a$, from the last inequation.
You get $a=\frac{1}{8},b=\frac{5}{24}$
Therefore $E[X]=3a+12b=3\frac{1}{8}+12\frac{5}{24}=\frac{23}{8}$
Then $var[X]=E[X^{2}]+(E[X])^{2}$, so $var[X]=(0a+1a+4a+9b+16b+25b)+(3a+12b)^{2}$
$var[X]=5a+50b+9a^{2}+72ab+144b^{2}=\frac{6767}{192}$